# what's the difference between request.on('error') and response.on('error')

Tags: node.js

when making an `http.request` there are 2 events that produce errors: `request.on('error')` and `response.on('error')`.

I can't see a difference because both errors come from the web server.

what's the difference between `thisError` and `thatError` ?

```
var request = http.request({hostname:"example.com"}, function(response){
    response.on('error', function(thisError){
     //what's the difference between thisError <<<<<<
    });
});
request.on('error', function(thatError){
    //and thatError      <<<<<
});
```

Comment: `request` and `response` are both writable streams. Writable streams can emit error events: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1 . From that perspective, there is no difference.

Comment: Yes, they both implement stream api's, which means they may emit ```error```. @FelixKling ```response``` is actually [IncommingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) which is ```ReadableStream```.

Comment: @EdinM: Ah, I was only looking at https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During a request you resolve a name, establish a connection, send a bunch of data, and each task could result in an error.

When you receive data through a response object, as an example the other end could close the connection unexpectedly.

Those errors are different and they must belong to the right structure, in this case respectively request and response.

Comment: Hello @skypjack as per this answer the `request error handler` should only be catching request related errors, but in my case I have `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` error which is an invalid response error, and this is only caught by the `request error handler`, and **NOT** the `response error handler`. Any ideas why?